# Mysterious internal routing

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, digital-ocean

I'm investigating some anomalies I found on a server I manage after installing Snort IDS.

I have ~10 Ubuntu production webservers that are set up with Ansible and regularly provisioned. One of them is displaying very strange routing of requests.

Lets say the server's IP public is `111.1.1.11`.

- It's a Digital Ocean droplet.
- It only has one NIC.
- `ifconfig` shows the NIC with public IP `111.1.1.11`.

When I look at the logs in Snort, and also when I monitor the network traffic with [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) I see that:

- All of the traffic I expect (ssh, https, an SQL port) is being routed to a host at a private address in the `10.0.0.0`-`10.255.255.255` range. Let's say it's: `10.20.0.10`.
- Traffic on other ports is *not* being redirected there, and is resolving to ports on `111.1.1.11`.

If I look through my `iptables` rules there are no mentions of this host `10.20.0.10`, or anything unusual with routing. `netstat` is not showing anything unusual. If I ping `10.20.0.10` I can see there is something there. I can't see any processes running on the server that are unexpected.

I can't figure out why or how traffic from external addresses is being routed to this private address. I've checked the other 10 servers (which are all configured exactly the same, via Ansible) and they don't have this strange routing behaviour. All their traffic resolves to regular ports on their respective public IPs.

Any ideas?

Update:

It seems like the network interface configuration is non-standard on our servers that are hosted with Digital Ocean.

Standard config:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

DO config:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
    dns-nameservers 67.207.67.2 67.207.67.3 # This is custom Digital Ocean DNS

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 111.1.1.11/20
    gateway 111.1.0.1

# control-alias eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.20.0.10/16
```

So that's part of the mystery solved. Our other DO hosted servers have a similar config (with different IPs, obviously).

The remaining issue is that our other DO-hosted servers *don't* route any incoming traffic to their addresses listed under "control-alias eth0", so I'm still confused as to why one server does, and the others don't.

Comment: Please check the output of `iptables-save`. By default the iptables command shows only the filter table. Run the tcpdump and check the traffic.

Comment: @AntonDanilov yes, I used `iptables -S` which I think gives the same output as `iptables-save`. Either way, there's nothing there that mentions the phantom host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that private address is what Digital Ocean calls an "Anchor IP", used internally for routing traffic from Floating IPs.

Somebody else had added a floating IP to that Droplet, and I didn't realise.

*/facepalm*

Well at least I've learnt something new, and maybe this will help some other confused syadmin some day.

**Possible solutions:**

- Get rid of the Floating IP
- Adapt Snort configuration (it was throwing a lot of false-positives for that traffic, and would have blocked most of it)